# Open a video player in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an app where I need to display a player with an embed youtube video. I have retrieve the data of a youtube playlist, and put them in a `TouchableHighlight`. I want now to display a player in a WebView, but just on top of my list. So when I'm clicking on a video, the list go down and a WebView take the place ? Is it possible ? Here is the code :

**Fetching data from YTApi**

```
_fetchPlaylist(){
    if(this.state.selectedIndex === 0) {
      return(
      fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=${results}&playlistId=PLSlVQ0kIy6qx-f5O3J3GwIEOO5Y52z43-&key=${apiKey}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const videoId = []
        res.items.forEach(item => {
          videoId.push(item)
        })
        this.setState({
          data:videoId
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
      )
    }
}
```

**displayWebView**

```
displayVideo(videoId){
      if(this.state.selectedIndex == 0){
        return(
          <View style = {{height:300}}>
          <WebView
          style={{flex:1}}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          source={{uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=x57qZ8Ym51s&list=${videoId}`}}
          />
          </View>
        )
      } else{
          return <View></View>
        }
}
```

**render**

```
<View style = {styles.containerPlaylist}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style = {styles.body}>
            {
              this.state.data.map((item,i) => 
              <TouchableHighlight
              key = {item.id.videoId}
              onPress = {()=> this.displayVideo(item.id.videoID)}>
              <View style = {styles.vids}>
                <Image
                  source = {{uri: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}
                  style = {{width: 120, height: 90,marginVertical:30, flexDirection:'column', alignSelf:'flex-start', backgroundColor:'#fff', resizeMode:'contain'}}
                   />
                    <Text style = {styles.vidText}>{item.snippet.title}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              )}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep webview in your layout and then need to manage two state,

1. to show and hide webview/video
2. to change the url of webview/video

Initialize the state like this along with your other state:

```
this.state = {
    showVideo: false,
    videoUrl: "default youtube url or empty string"
}
```

then create your layout like this and adjust your styling as per your need:

```
<View style={styles.containerPlaylist}>
  <ScrollView>
    {this.state.showVideo &&
      <View style={{ height: 300 }}>
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          source={{ uri: this.state.videoUrl }}
        />
      </View>
    }
    <View style={styles.body}>
      {
        this.state.data.map((item, i) =>
          <TouchableHighlight
            key={item.id.videoId}
            onPress={() => this.displayVideo(item.id.videoID)}>
            <View style={styles.vids}>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url }}
                style={{ width: 120, height: 90, marginVertical: 30, flexDirection: 'column', alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: '#fff', resizeMode: 'contain' }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.vidText}>{item.snippet.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )}
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

and change your function something like this to display video which has been clicked:

```
displayVideo(videoId) {
    this.setState({
      videoUrl: `https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=x57qZ8Ym51s&list=${videoId}`
      showVideo: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly ! Just one more question if I want to display a default video first and then when I click on my list it will replace it, how can I do it ? I tried in `displayVideos` to make an if statement with `if(this.state.showVideo)`then display the default and `else` display the dynamic webView but it didn't work

Comment: `this.state = {
    showVideo: true,
    videoUrl: "default youtube url"
}`
initialize state like this to show default video and to open video which has been clicked from playlist, set `videoUrl` state in `displayVideo` function.

Comment: Yeah but my videoUrl state is already initialized with the click response no ? I'm posting it In a new response, I may doing it wrong

Comment: If I use `this.setState({videoUrl: "default url"});` it always display me the same video with the default url.